# SSH Wrapping with HTTPS Portable?

Tags: ssh, proxy, putty, https

I was wondering if there was a way that I could wrap my ssh connection in https, even if my school supplies a certificate for https since they use smoothwall, and if I was able to do this on CENTOS, and also, I am using PuTTy on the client, and this has to be portable (USB Stick) so that I could use it on any PC at my school.